# how to serialize some attribute in some condition

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

When using XML serialization to serialize a class, how to make some attribute be outputted conditionally. i.e. In some case, it output this attribute, in other cases, it does not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create an additional property which is called `MyPropertySpecified`, which returns a boolean.
When this property returns true, the `MyProperty` property will be serialized.  When it returns false, it will not be serialized.

Also, you'd want to decorate that property with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`, so that this specific property is not serialized.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool NameSpecified
    {
        get  { return Name != "secret"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP wants the attribute to be output(included in the xml).

Comment: As I see it, he wants to output (serialize) some property of this class to xml in some cases, and in other cases he doesn't want to.  This is solved by my answer.  Whether he wants this property to be serialized as an attribute, or as an element can be defined by the other XMLSerializationAttributes that are available.  (XmlAttribute for instance).

Comment: Darn, I gotta try this. Didn't know that xD +1

Comment: I did not know this; just read about it [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). I guess I have to be careful when using Specified in a property name.

Comment: any formal documentation about this solution?

Answer (score 4):

While works and is a rather short solution, the `propertyNameSpecified` pattern has some drawbacks in my opinion (pollutes the interface of your class; relies on property names; introduces implicit behavior).

If you only need to implement a simple condition (e.g. don't serialize a default value), then the [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute is a better choice.

For example:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    [DefaultValue("2002")]
    public string Year;
}
```

If Year has the value "2002", it will be omitted from the XML output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OnSerializingAttribute** while serializing which allows us to invoke method before serialization. You can get more information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Besides that, what would he do if the specific attribute were a value type? As far as I know OnSerializing can be used to set values, etc during Serialization, it does not change wether the attribute will be serialized. I assume you expect null values to not be serialized, but in case of value types there will be a value in the property and thus it would require additional work to get the behaviour the OP wants, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Imho you would need to implement IXmlSerializable on the class and implement the WriteXml and ReadXml methods in such a way that they only write the attribute based upon the conditions you specify and can handle reading with or without that particular attribute present upon deserialization.

[IXmlSerializable at Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)

Comment: WriteXml() doesn't allow you to cause the element to be omitted entirely.

Comment: Implementing IXmlSerializable has you build the serialized object for the entire class instance in xml completely. Therefore you can omit attributes and elements for any properties of class X.
Sure, you can't omit the class level element, which makes sense. That would either produce an xml document without a root element or it should be handled by the class instance that 'has' class X as one of it's serialized members.